# Android program to: Display random image for 90 seconds then switch

Tags: android, image, random, timer

I'm new to android. I need to make a program that is very basic. It needs to display a random image from my drawing folder. I can do that part because frank n stein posted [How To Display Random images on image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549705/how-to-display-random-images-on-image-view)

But I need it to stay on the screen for 90 seconds (and count down) or until a user clicks a button. Can someone help? I would really appreciate it. If you post an answer please assume I know absolutely nothing...barely the basics. But I'm trying to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for loop` with `Thread.sleep()` or a `CountDownTimer` or `AlarmManager` or a `Handler` with `postDelayed` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android alarm manager with broadcast receiver,you will set alarm +90 second to this time and receiver the alarm or you must to use timer.But timer is spending battery more than alarm manager.
You can follow this tutorial for alarm manager and i think you must follow :)
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/