# Background black when programmatically setting activity background

Tags: android

I have a fullscreen activity, for which I want to programmatically set the background. I have four different images in my drawable folder, and each time the activity is created, I want to randomly choose one for the background. Here is my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null);
int[] images = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};
Random rand = new Random();
layout.setBackgroundResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mkessler.MyApp.MyActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:textColor="#33b5e5"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
        style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="@color/black_overlay"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dummy_button"
            style="?metaButtonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Unimportant text"
            android:onClick="someFunction"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

However, when I run the app on my phone, the background is just black. The same happens when I try to set it using a specific one of the images. Needless, when I set it from the XML file it works fine.

EDIT:
Just to clarify, even when I try to set it to a given image programmatically and not though the XML file, I get a black background. I think focusing on the random aspect of the question isn't going to get anywhere.

EDIT #2: Minimum API of my project set to 15. Don't know if this is relevant, but in case anyone thinks it matters...

Comment: your rand may be greater than images array size , make sure that it is between 0 and 3

Comment: @AsmaaRashad Isn't that what `rand.nextInt(images.length)` gives me?

Comment: Check here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523005/how-set-background-drawable-programmatically-in-android

Comment: check that answer for generating random number in range http://stackoverflow.com/a/21049922/5470794

Comment: @AsmaaRashad, what that answer says is "yes, that's exactly what `rand.nextInt(images.length)` gives me."
@Tasos, I've read it several times already, but I'll admit I haven't tried every last suggestion there - some are deprecated and some need a minimal API higher than my app defined. I'd still appreciate any input on why the obvious way isn't working.

Comment: @AsmaaRashad Random.nextInt(n) returns a random int in range[0, n-1]

Comment: There is another easy way to generate a random image as you have named them 1,2,3  eg (final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);) --  and to set (getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
                getApplicationContext()))) --- check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549705/how-to-display-random-images-on-image-view

Comment: From your EDIT:  -- what does the Logcat say?? have you checked that??

Comment: @Tasos, I honestly only check the logcat when the app crashes, which is doesn't. What should I be looking for there?

Comment: The Logcat also shows Warnings -- just monitor it and see if it shows you anything suspicious when you change the image

Comment: @Tasos, it's too much to copy to a comment, but from what I can tell, there's nothing in the logcat about the image.

Comment: In AS -- To filter just for the App in the search box add the name of your package eg (com.nyapplicaionname) -- you get less output

Comment: @Tasos, it already is filtered just for the app.

Comment: then im not sure -- the random image is created ok and its in the drawable folder so you should be good to go  as you say -- Add the (R.layout.activity_my) xml to your Question, looks like the problem is there

Comment: I think you need to set the inflater to true  -- eg - (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, true);)  --- check here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get view via `LayoutInflater`, if your `Activity` has xml layout and you called `setContentView(int resId)` you just find your root view and set background.

```
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(...);
layout.setBackgroundResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
```

If you want to get view via `LayoutInflater` :

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null);
layout.setBackgroundResource(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]);
setContentView(layout);
```

Comment: I used your first suggestion instead of the `LayoutInflater` and it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my, null);
int[] images = {R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3,R.drawable.img4};
Random rand = new Random();

final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]));
} else {
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(images[rand.nextInt(images.length)]));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that already, and I still get a black background.

Comment: @faerubin I edited the answer. Try that one too. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll edit my original question to clarify this, but for your benefit - I defined my minimum API level to 15, and the logic under `else` requires min of 16, so my code doesn't compile.