# Random background in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner on Android Studio, and java, i want to create a random background of view images, i try to use this [How To Display Random images on image view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549705/how-to-display-random-images-on-image-view) , but not working, this code doesn't generate any image
Please, can someone help me to resolve this code or to create another code to random background.

I use this code to generate images

```
    final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.rnd_images);

    final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgRandom);
    // I have 3 images named img_0 to img_2, so...
    final String str = "img_" + rnd.nextInt(2);
    img.setImageDrawable
    (
        getResources().getDrawable(getResourceID(str, "drawable",
            getApplicationContext()))
        );
}

protected final static int getResourceID
(final String resName, final String resType, final Context ctx)
{
    final int ResourceID =
        ctx.getResources().getIdentifier(resName, resType,
            ctx.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (ResourceID == 0)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException
        (
            "No resource string found with name " + resName
            );
    }
    else
    {
        return ResourceID;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your code and explain how it doesn't work

Comment: I put my code in post, it doesn't work beacause I think I do something wrong. It doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't generate nothing.

Comment: Please provide a [_minimal_, complete and verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows this problem.  Most of what you have is likely unrelated to your problem.

Comment: Ok, I put what you want in post. Thanks for reply.

Comment: And I try this code `int[] cards = {R.drawable.i1, R.drawable.i2, R.drawable.i3};
    Random n = new Random();
    Resources resources = getResources();
    imgRandom.setImageResource(cards[n]);` but I have a problem with **setImageResource** is red and Android Studio says that "cannot resolve symbol setImageResource"