# App crashes on startup, why?

Tags: android

I am trying to change background color on start of app.

Here is the method called from `onCreate()`:

```
private void setBackground() {
        String[] rColors = getRandomColors();
        int rColor = new Random().nextInt(rColors.length);
        ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(rColors[rColor]));
    }
```

This method crashes the app when trying to start it. Is there another better way to change background color in code?

`getRandonColors()` returns a `String[]` with names of some colors I defined in `colors.xml`

EDIT:

```
String[] rColors = getRandomColors();
int rColor = new Random().nextInt(rColors.length);
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
int i = MainActivityNew.this.getResources().getIdentifier(rColors[rColor],"color",MainActivityNew.this.getPackageName());
constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(i);
```

EDIT2:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.asus.wetr, PID: 12941
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.asus.wetr/com.asus.wetr.activities.MainActivityNew}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color
                                                       at android.graphics.Color.parseColor(Color.java:235)
                                                       at com.asus.wetr.activities.MainActivityNew.setBackground(MainActivityNew.java:214)
                                                       at com.asus.wetr.activities.MainActivityNew.setUpUIComponents(MainActivityNew.java:143)
                                                       at com.asus.wetr.activities.MainActivityNew.onCreate(MainActivityNew.java:111)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: This line `constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(rColors[rColor]));` isn't going to work. You should use reflection to get the id of your color given its name. Then properly get the color resource basing on that id.

Comment: @Rotwang Thanks for your comment. How does that work? Do you have any link on it?

Comment: The same way of when you want to show a random image given its name. But this time you use `"color"` instead of `"drawable"` as the type for `getIdentifier()`. And of course, you want to use `getResources().getColor()` instead of `getResources().getDrawable()`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20550354/2649012

Comment: @Rotwang Oh I see. I did try (added it to my post under EDIT), but it displays the same color everytime.

Comment: Show your error log.

Comment: This part "Color.parseColor(rColors‌​[rColor])"  is causing the problems @Bryan

Comment: @Carlton Yes, but what problems is it causing? Copy and paste the error log into your question. It is difficult to debug an error without knowing what that error is...

Comment: It's actually `getResources().getColor(getIdentifier(rColors[rColor], "color", ...`

Comment: @Rotwang getColor() is depreciated, I should use ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.someColor) but I cant figure out how to use that with my randomcolorness?

Comment: @Bryan I added it to my post under EDIT2. IF you look under EDIT1 youll see another try but also unsuccesful one.

Comment: I got it to work, but had to update to `minSdkVersion 23`. This is how it worked: `int i = MainActivityNew.this.getResources().getColor(MainActivityNew.this.getResources().getIdentifier(rColors[rColor],"color",MainActivityNew.this.getPackageName()),null);`

Comment: `MainActivityNew.this` (if it's really required - is it?) could be replaced by `getBaseContext()` or `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: @Rotwang It is [almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/5115932) to use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()` instead of the activity context.

Comment: ... if you can use it. It depends. There are cases where you **need** to use `getApplicationContext()` or `getBaseContext()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [`TypedArray`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray) resource instead of a `String[]` to store an array of colors. This will provide auto-complete and error detection for the reference to your colors, making the process less error-prone. You can do this in your `colors.xml` file, or create a separate `arrays.xml` file:

```
<resources>

    <array name="colors">
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/orange</item>
        <item>@color/yellow</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/indigo</item>
        <item>@color/violet</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

Then you can reference this array in your `Activity` code:

```
private int getRandomColor() {
    TypedArray a = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);

    int random = new Random().nextInt(a.length());
    int defValue = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.red);
    int color = a.getColor(random, defValue);

    a.recycle();

    return color;
}
```

Then you can call this to set the background color for the entire `Window` (or a specific `View` if you prefer):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
```